# SSDT doesn't recognize STRING_SPLIT function in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2016

Try to use SQL Server 2016 STRING_SPLIT function in a stored procedure. It parses correct in SSMS. But in SSDT (latest version), the function can't be resolved, so the project cannot be compiled. Anybody know how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: What is the compatibility level of the database project set to? (See second screenshot here https://simonlearningsqlserver.wordpress.com/2013/11/08/controlling-database-compatibility-level-with-ssdt/)

Comment: Thanks. I never checked. It is SQL Server 2016 (130). I think it should be fine.

Comment: Well if you're certain that you are using the most up to date version of SSDT report it here https://connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Upvote the following connect issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2906200/ssdt-failing-to-compile-if-string-split-is-used

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in SSDT and we have a work item internally to fix it.  The only workaround I can suggest, unfortunately, is to remove the STRING_SPLIT from the stored procedure definition and then alter the definition of the stored procedure as a post-deploy script action.

Comment: Thanks. I will continue to use my own version of the string_split until Microsoft releases the fix.

Comment: Still doesn't recognize it in my installation!